# TypeError: connection.playStream is not a function discord bot

Tags: discord.js

```
switch(args[0]){
case 'ping':
message.reply('pong!');
    break;
case 'play':
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
    if(args[1]){
        const connection = message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(args[1]));

    }else{
    message.reply('Tio, el link joder');
    }

    } else {
    message.reply('Pero tio, únete al canal de voz');
    }
break;  
case 'info':
    message.reply('No soy el FBI,hippie');
    break;
case 'clear':
    if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Hippie,que te falta un argumento')
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
    break;
        }
         });
```

I tried to seek in other questions the solutions but none of this are what i need or doesnt work,here is the error TypeError: connection.playStream is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In the new v12 update, playStream has been defunct.

the new proper code is

```
server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
```

instead of playStream it is just play.

Comment: Now say that connection.play isnt a function too

Answer (score 0):

ive been troubleshooting the same code your running, here is the full play,stop and skip commands. I cant figure out the queue though but this should fix your errors with it not running.

```
case 'play':

                if(usedCommandRecently4.has(message.author.id)){
                    message.reply("Your using this command to fast!");
                } else{
                    function play(connection, message){
                        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                        server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                        server.queue.shift();

                        message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Adding song to queue!");

                        server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                            if(server.queue[0]){
                                play(connection, message);
                            }else {
                                connection.disconnect();
                            }
                        })
                    }

                    if(!args[1]){
                        message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n you need to provide a link!!");
                        return;
                    }

                    if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                        message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n You must be in a voice channel to play music!");
                        return;
                    }

                    if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                        queue: []
                    }

                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                    server.queue.push(args[1]);

                    if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                        server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
                        play(connection, message);

                    })

                    usedCommandRecently4.add(message.author.id);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        usedCommandRecently4.delete(message.author.id)
                    }, 10000);
                }

            break;

            case 'skip':

                if(usedCommandRecently3.has(message.author.id)){
                    message.reply("Your using this command to fast!");
                } else{
                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
                    if(server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
                    message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Skipping the current song!")

                    usedCommandRecently3.add(message.author.id);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        usedCommandRecently3.delete(message.author.id)
                    }, 3000);
                }

            break;

            case 'stop':
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];
                if(message.guild.voice.connection){
                    for(var i = server.queue.length -1; i >=0; i--){
                        server.queue.splice(i, 1);
                    }

                    server.dispatcher.end();
                    message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Ending the queue and Leaving the voice channel! \n This bot is in early development! \n if you have any problems with it dm Justice#6770!")
                    console.log('stopped the queue')
                }
            }

            if(message.guild.connection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
```